# Finding angles using arctan

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Given $z = 12 - 5j$ find the angle.

The formula is angle $= \arctan(y/x)$. Because $y$ is negative, we need to subtract the answer from $2\pi$. (Or more accurately, because the sketch I made tells me that the angle I want is the angle outside from the angle I'm actually calculating, we have to subtract from $2\pi$. I have to sketch/plot everything or I'm basically just guessing.)

Except slotting a negative $y$ into this equation doesn't give the right answer.

angle $= 2\pi - \arctan(-5/12)$ is wrong

angle $= 2\pi - \arctan(5/12)$ is right

Could someone explain why?

Comment: The period of $\tan$ is $\pi$ not $2\,\pi$ so further work may be necessary. See [atan2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2).

Comment: I need a tutor really bad. :/

Comment: This is easier than it looks and it is sometimes better to find out by yourself. From the [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation) notice that for $x>0$ your formula applies while for $x<0$ you have to add or subtract $\pi$ (depending of the wished range) since $\arctan$ can only return a value in the $[-\frac{\pi}2,\frac{\pi}2]$ range. For $x=0$ you have anyway the division by $0$ problem and the answer can only be $-\frac{\pi}2$, undefined or $+\frac{\pi}2$.

Answer (score 2):

The argument angle of $z$ should satisfy $$\tan\theta = \frac{\Im (z)}{\Re (z)}$$
So you might be temped to use $\theta = \arctan\left(\frac{-5}{12}\right)\approx-0.395$. However, for the range of $[0,2\pi)$, there are actually two such $\theta$'s that satisfy the $\tan \theta$ requirement:

$$\theta_1= \pi +(-0.395), \ \theta_2 = 2\pi + (-0.395)$$

because the period of $\tan \theta$ is $\pi$.

Which $\theta$ to choose to determine $\arg z$? You have to check the quadrant of the argument of $z$.

Since $\Re (z) >0$ and $\Im(z) < 0$, you should be looking for a $\theta$ in the fourth quadrant, and $\theta_2$ is the answer within the $[0,2\pi)$ range.

$$\arg z = 2\pi + \arctan\left(\frac{-5}{12}\right) \approx 5.888$$